# mongodb aggregate with more than one project operation

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am doing a time series application (each document has a timestamp and a value) and need to aggregate values by grouping into time slots (intervals).  To make the time slot, the timestamp is divided and then floored.  For example a slot of 1-minute:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {value:1, "timestamp": {$subtract: ["$time", new Date('1970-01-01')]}} },
  {$project: {value:1, "time2": {$divide, ["$timestamp",60000]}}},
  {$project: {value:1, "timeslot": {$floor: "$time2"}}},
  {$group: {_id: "$timeslot", avg: {$avg, "$value"}}}
])
```

This did the job, but very clumsy: 3 $project in sequence, value:1 repeated each time. Is there a way to combine the $subtract, $divide, $floor... ?

Moreover, are there convenience methods in com.mongodb.client.model.Projections to do this? I am using Java mongodb-driver 3.6.2.

Comment: What do you actually think that math is doing? Are you actually trying to get a time interval? Because simply dividing by 60,000 would not be correct if that is your intent.

Comment: Don't worry, I just read that you said 1 minute interval. Been answered already.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Upvoted answer to that question.